# WPF action on LostFocus textbox

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm working on a WPF application and i have a little problem.

I have 1 ToggleButton and 1 TextBox. When i click on the ToggleButton, the TextBox apears and gets focus. This is good. But now i want that when i click on another textbox or just somewhere else, that the textbox loses his focus and disapears. I tried this with Differnet triggers and setters, but can't get it to work.

My code now:

```
  <ToggleButton x:Name="SearchButton" Width="100" Height="100" BorderThickness="0"  Margin="580,0,0,0" Template="{DynamicResource ButtonBaseControlTemplate1}" Panel.ZIndex="1">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=SearchButton}" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=SearchBox}" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=SearchBox}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton><TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" Margin="100,33,0,34" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=SearchButton, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}" Opacity="0" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Arial" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FF7F7F7F" BorderThickness="0">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="TextBox.IsFocused" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False" TargetName="SearchButton" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: Do you need to do this without code-behind?

Comment: well i like it more without, but if i need to use it, no problem then.

Comment: You can show a complete example? For me, construction `IsFocused = "False"` works.

Comment: Example with button and textbox?

Comment: Yes, all of the code where you try to set the `IsFocused=False` in trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact, that the styles in the WPF separated from each other, it's just a bunch of settings setters. We can say, that two different styles for controls, with two different visual trees. So when you're trying to style `TextBox` to access `ToggleButton` it does not work, because of its visual tree no `ToggleButtons`.

In WPF for editing elements in the visual tree, and control in particular, uses a template control or controls placed within view of one `Style` (but this is usually done with the help of templates, such as `DataTemplate`, or with `ControlTemplate`).

I think it will suit you to control the `Expander`. It already has `ToggleButton` and content. Example:

XAML

```
<Expander Header="SearchButton">
    <TextBox Text="SearchBox: Opened" Background="Gainsboro" />
</Expander>
```

Output

[image]

To change the view of `Expander`, you need to change his `Style`. With it, you can set any form and view of control.

For more information see:

[Expander in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms750485.aspx)

[Styling and Templating in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)

[Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Using a ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

Comment: The expander is great! But how can i let it all fold, when the textbox loses his focus?

Comment: @user2499088: You mean, if the `Expander` will lose focus, then close it?